# Why does my car jerk and jump when I stop?

Tags: repair

I have a 2012 Buick Reale and it jumps and jerks when I stop at light or stop sign, and it also flutters doing take off or acceleration. What could it be?

Comment: You seem to have a misfire problem. Is the check engine light on?

Comment: Do you mean a Buick Regal? What do you mean by fluttering? As in a sound? What engine does the car have? Is it a turbo?

Comment: Does it idle poorly too?  What happens when you are in neutral and step on the gas?